# For /f only outputting top level from forfiles /s

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following directory structure structure:

```
DirA
    DirB
     fileb1
     fileb2
    DirC
     filec1
     filec2
fileA1
my.appcache
fileA2
```

And I'm trying to write a batch file that will output the file names with their relative directories to a .appcache or .txt file.

Here is the script which lies in the directory above DirA

```
cd DirA

del /Q "my.appcache"

fsutil file createnew my.appcache 0

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion



for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @relpath >> my.appcache" ') do (
  set "file=%%~A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !file:~2!
  endlocal
)

PAUSE
```

However, the script only sends DirA's contents to my.appcache. However, if i just let it echo to the cmd window, it lists all the files inside DirB and DirC too.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: It's creating my.appcaches in DIRB and DIRC and outputting the relevant section to them.

Comment: Instead of `>> my.appcache`, write `>> \full\path\to\my.appcache`, because `forfiles` passes the currently iterated directory location over to the command line after the `/c` switch as the current working directory; another option is to redirect the output of the whole `forfiles` loop: `(forfiles /s ... /c "...") > my.appcache`; in addition I recommend to use mask `*` rather than `*.*`, because `forfiles` does not return files with no extension if `*.*` is given (like `dir` would for example)...

Comment: I am not understanding why you are using `FORFILES` inside a `FOR /F`? This makes no sense at all.  There is no need to use `FORFILES` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is a bit hard to follow because you are combining `for /f` with `forfiles`. Those two commands do a similar job so people typically use one or the other. Anyway, your issue is that you are appending to a file in the current directory, which changes as the `forfiles` command traverses the tree. You'll find a separate my.appcache file in each directory. You should instead do the redirection in one place:

```
(forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @relpath") > my.appcache
```

(and you don't need any of the other scaffolding.)

By the way, if you want to search for ALL files (not just those containing a dot in their names) then the `/m *` option is the default, so you can just leave it out:

```
(forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @relpath") > my.appcache
```

Comment: that's solved it, thanks for that. I'm using the nested loop so that the outer loop can do some string manipulation

Comment: @rory If you want to remove the quotes and the leading ".\", you can still do that with a one-liner: `forfiles /s /c "cmd /v:on /c set p=@relpath&echo !p:~3,-1!"`

Comment: By the way, the above one-liner using `cmd /v:on /c set p=@relpath` might not work if a file or directory name contains a pair of `!` characters.